# Fit to screen all widgets

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the screen shots. I want this buttons display in fit to screen for all devices.

I want to remove space after **Button6** and fit all buttons in screen.

[image]

Comment: then use layout_weight as an attribute in your buttons in your xml file.

Comment: How possible when use relativelayout?

Comment: Since this is straight vertical, conside using LinearLayout. But IF you must use RelativeLayout, then you can add your button into a LinearLayout and then add the layout_weight attribute.

Comment: Why do you want to go for Relative Layout, when you are able to achieve something you want the other way, any specific reasons for moving from Linear to Relative Layout ???

Comment: Actually when press a button then display another view. it is for all buttons when click one button it show view and hide others button's view. so use relativelayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it should be fill_parent in layout_height.

Comment: Both gives the same UI. Thanks for the piece of info.

Answer (score 2):

Use :

res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml

res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml

res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml

set button height

```
<!-- in values-ldpi/dimens.xml -->
<dimen name="height">25dip</dimen>

<!-- in values-mdpi/dimens.xml -->
<dimen name="height">30dip</dimen>

<!-- in values-hdpi/dimens.xml -->
<dimen name="height">40dip</dimen>
```